# Buffing your java program

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

im working on something here on java... im gonna need to run about 6milion sql queries in this program.
so ive tested it on much much less and it seems kind of slow. too slow.

using 700m ram (out of 8g). so i got a nice argument to higher it to 1500m... still not fast enough.

so ive been searching around and looks like there are tons of ideas how to make your program run faster... and my question to you guys is -

how do you buff your program's performance?

Comment: Do you know what a profiler is?

Comment: You first have to find out **why** it is running slow, and then focus on fixing the cause of the slowness. Just trying random things is not a very effective way to solve a problem.

Comment: its not a matter of code... its the matter of running millions of sql queries... and looks like my computer is limiting the program preformance.
ive already made everything that is running before the sql part really quick by creating smaller beans where i can and such.... still , the connection to the sql isnt that quick...

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of performance analysis tools available for java. One such "[VisualVM](http://java.dzone.com/articles/best-kept-secret-jdk-visualvm)" is available as part of jdk itself so you can start with that.